# How can I make a question for a game that has been updated?

Tags: discussion

There are games that are updated online (for example Gran Turismo 5).

This cause that some questions and answers are valid in a period of time, but when a new patch is released they become wrong (or not the best answer).

For example:

There is a question for Gran Turismo 5:

What is the best way to earn money?

For the firsts versions of Gran Turismo 5, the answers were correct (Do the "Like the Wind Event"), but after the patch 1.13, the best way is doing the "Seasonals Events".

What can we do?

Comment: One of the best parts about stackexchange is that you're never prevented from adding new answers to an old question!

If the answer has changed significantly, why not post an answer with the updated data?

Answer (score 9):

If the *answers* are outdated, you can just provide an updated one, or edit an existing one. This is both supported and highly encouraged!

However, if you *don't know* the new answer, you have a few options:

- Leave a comment on the outdated answer, and hopefully the owner will come back and update it (they'll get a notification in their inbox when someone leaves a comment on their answer)
- Spend some of your own reputation to [place a bounty on the question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty) asking for an up-to-date answer.

Comment: Placing a bounty is the best way to encourage a fresh answer on an outdated question.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Brant said, if you don't know the answer to a question with outdated answers:

- Make a suggested edit to any of the questions or answers. You can normally find something in a question or answer which could be improved. Such as grammar or improving the wording for clarity. This will bump the question to the front page, and hopefully draw some attention to it. If you do this, you should leave a comment on the question stating the current answers out outdated as well.